# How to import osCommerce store into Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, oscommerce

I spent quite a while trying to import an osCommerce store into Magento 1.7.0.2 and wanted to document it somewhere relevant.

The [official migration tool](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/oscommerce-migration-tool.html) seems like the best free option, but it was clearly never completed or properly tested (to be fair, it is marked as Beta).

It's still possible to get it to work, with a *lot* of tweaks. I was able to import categories, products, orders and customers using the method in my answer below:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the extension from http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/oscommerce-migration-tool.html, but then upgrade it with the most recent version (from 1.5 trunk) in SVN:

```
svn co http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.5-trunk/app/code/core/Mage/Oscommerce/ Oscommerce
```

You should then be able to run your import following these instructions:

- Back up your database
- Copy all your osCommerce product images into media/import (and make them writable by the webserver)
- VERY IMPORTANT: Change the language for the admin interface to English (United States) - or no products will appear even after a succesful import. You can switch it back afterwards
- Set up your import profile (from System > Import/Export > osCommerce)
- Click on Run Profile on the left, and then the "Check Requirements" button
- If you only have one store/website, the Website Code field will be "base".

Good luck!

Comment: I followed all instructions it works fine for category import but when I import products, it shows me this error message http://i.imgur.com/dvJ90JE.png?1

Comment: Shows shipping not available error for imported customer . This works once we save the user again from the back-end.Not practical as we have many customer's.  Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I used [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page) to import products, categories and imagesto magento.
It works pretty well and is very quick.
Imported 6500 products in under 2 mins. If you do that with the official importer it takes hours.
I like the possibility to import via a sql query that defines the datamodel instead of working with csv files.
 
There are some strange effects if you have utf8 chars but if you are english only, you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

In response to dearlbry, (I can't comment for lack of points, however..) I would like to point out as a helpful warning to anyone using this method, that it will send 'subscription success' email to customers as they import from OSCommerce. This can be extremely frustrating and cause a bit of a rift with customers if you're not careful. More info here: [enter link description here](http://www.boostingecommerce.com/importing-customers-into-magento-without-newsletter-subscription-notification)